# Cloning old Quantum drive using 68 pin to 50 pin adapter

Tags: hard-disk, troubleshooting

I’m now trying to clone a 50 pin SCSI drive on XW8000 machine. The cable is 68 pin SCSI and has a terminator at the end, my `dd` command is able to copy the drive to USB, but whenever I try to restore the file into an identical HDD, it gives me these errors:

> Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 1792, lost async page write.

Are these bad sectors on the drive? Or do you think a cable problem? I’ve changed my set up twice and still same errors. However, I would think I could boot the drive at least partially, and nothing is coming up.

System is able to recognize drive and access it, as I can create an identical `.img` file on my USB drive (USB 3, formatted EXT4). I’m using:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=64kB conv=sync,noerror
```

I’m using a straight 50 pin 68 pin adapter to connect drive from cable harness. My master drive is connected to harness and running Ubuntu.

Any ideas on what I could try?

Comment: There are two different schemes for 68-position wiring (wide SCSI); LVD is the more  modern, and single-ended is the common scheme used with 50 pin drives.   Host, drive, and terminator must all be capable of the same type of signaling.   Part  numbers?

Comment: If you're imaging an old hard drive, you don't want `dd`, you want `ddrescue`.  Much better handling of bad sectors and other glitches.

Comment: why are you using a block size of 64K ? you normally want to match the sector size, 512 bytes

Comment: Camelcccc, I noticed that too. And I’ve changed the bs = 512 and same errors.

Comment: @Whit3rd what do you think?

Comment: @Marcus The termination being external to the TM21S001, you want the jumper block (PK/TE/A0/A1/A2) to have only one jumper installed, at A1 to make SCSI ID 2.   Other than that, you want to  know whether the other (68-pin working drive) and the terminator and host adapter are all capable of SE SCSI operation; the quickest way to tell is by the SCSI glyphs (see <http://www.scsi.solutions/index.php?page=scsi>).

Comment: Thank you @Whit3rd. Link doesn’t seem to work

Comment: @Marcus - looks like the link ingested an invisible character... try <https://iec.net/home/technical-information/small-computer-system-interface-scsi/scsi-symbols/>

Comment: @Marcus The 53C1030 chip  docs say "integrated LVDlink transceivers for direct attach to either Low Voltage Differential (LVD) or single-ended (SE) SCSI buses ".   It should detect SE and downshift, unless it has software or wiring issues.